# Make an executable function which can be called from within python

Tags: python, executable

I've written a function which I want to be able to call from within python, ie like `w=max(temps)`, say. I've done `chmod +x flt.py`. I've made a directory `/home/mike/passive` . Passive contains 2 files `flt.py` and `__init__.py`. Flt.py contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
def fltflt(x, prices_list):
    and then some calculations
return a,b
```

I want to be able to write

```
x,y=flt([list1],[list2])
```

When I try to run it with

```
from passive import flt 
x,y=flt([list1],[list2])
```

I get `NameError: name 'passive' is not defined`

What have I done wrong?
Is passive in the right place?
I'm on ubuntu and python 2.5.2

Comment: Where is your program? In order to be found, the module `passive` needs to be in the same directory as the program that imports it, or in the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Put `flt.py` in the same directory as your program, then use `from flt import fltflt`

Comment: Anyway after you resolve this, your `import` will be importing the module `flt` from package `passive`; you'll still need to call `flt.fltflt(...)`. Don't use a package, just put your function in `passive.py` and say `from passive import fltflt`.

Comment: 2.5.2 is really old.  Is there a specific reason you need to use it?

Answer (score 0):

in order for you to be able to do `from passive import flt`, the python package `passive` must be in one of the folders in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. In your example, the folder passive is under `/home/mike`, so add that to your `PYTHONPATH` from the terminal like so

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/mike
```

the above command would add your home folder to the `PYTHONPATH` for the current terminal session. afterwards, you can run `from passive import flt`. Note that due to your package structure, this would import the `flt.py` module, in order to execute the `flt()` function your would need to call `flt.flt()` in your code.

If this is something you'd do very often, you may want to consider adding the above terminal command to your `.bash_profile` so that it's automatically executed every time you fire up the terminal